# android test case. how to get the services running?

Tags: android, testing, service

I have a test case in which i am starting a service by clicking a  button. After this i want to verify if it has started or not. how can i do this?

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            String serv = service.service.getClassName();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

i used this in my test cases but `getSystemServices()` is not recognized?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you run this code from? Either way you need a `Context` in order to use `getSystemService()`

```
Context context = ...; // get your context


private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```